# LongClick in a graph

Tags: android, graph, android-studio, long-click

I am trying to implement a longclick in a graph to set an alarm threshold in there and then the user will be warned if the graph (which reprensents mailboxes) is too important. But my problem comes with long click the normal click is handled but nothing happens when i put the onLong Click here is my code :

```
     @Override
     public void onClick(final int index) {
        if(index==-1)return;

            ((MailboxBar)g.getBars().get(index)).getMailboxId();

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create() ;
        alertDialog.setTitle(g.getBars().get(index).getName());
        alertDialog.setMessage("N° de la BAL + Détails");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.menu_icon);
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.close_dialog), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
     alertDialog.show();
    }
});
g.isLongClickable();
g.setOnLongClickListener(new BarGraph.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int index = 0;
        ((MailboxBar)g.getBars().get(index)).getMailboxId();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

g is supposed to be a barGraph where my graph is.
Thhank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to say:

```
g.setLongClickable(true);
```

instead of:

```
g.isLongClickable();
```